# How to optimise MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, performance, aggregation-framework

Our MongoDB database has a collection of companies and a collection of users. I'm running an aggregation pipeline, the details of which vary based on various filters chosen by an administrator, but below is a simple example. The `companies` collection has approximately 15 entries, and there are currently around 40,000 entries in the `users` collection.

Our aggregation returns user data, but must contain the `companyname` from the `companies` collection (there may also be filtering on the company depending on what options are chosen). A `user` document contains an array of subdocuments for `reports` - we need to include the last report date for possible sorting/filtering, too. The only other non-standard thing is that there is an object field `keydata` which needs to be included for searching. This object will be different for every user.

With only 40,000 records in the `users` collection, this aggregation is currently taking approximately five seconds. Eventually, we will have millions of records in the database, so I need a far more performant way of searching records.

Any pointers, please?

```
[
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            let: {
                cref: "$companyref",
                companyname: "$companyname",
            },
            as: "users",
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $eq: ["$$cref", "$companyref"],
                        },
                    },
                },
                {
                    $addFields: {
                        lastreportdate: {
                            $arrayElemAt: [
                                {
                                    $slice: ["$reports.date", -1],
                                },
                                0,
                            ],
                        },
                        kd: {
                            $objectToArray: "$keydata",
                        },
                        name: {
                            $concat: ["$firstname", " ", "$lastname"],
                        },
                        companyname: "$$companyname",
                    },
                },
                {
                    $match: {
                        $or: [
                            {
                                "kd.v": /searchstring/,
                            },
                            {
                                name: /searchstring/,
                            },
                            {
                                email: /searchstring/,
                            },
                            {
                                userref: /searchstring/,
                            },
                            {
                                username: /searchstring/,
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                },
                {
                    $project: {
                        kd: 0,
                        lastreportdate: 0,
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$users",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false,
        },
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$users",
        },
    },
    {
        $project: {
            userref: 1,
            keydata: 1,
            email: 1,
            zipcode: 1,
            companyref: 1,
            companyname: 1,
            firstname: 1,
            lastname: 1,
            name: 1,
            reports: 1,
            lastlogin: 1,
        },
    },
]
```

Collection `companies` has an index on `companyref` and collection `users` has an index on `userref`.

Comment: What are your indexes? Have you indexed the fields that are used in `$match` and `$lookup`(i.e. `companyref`...)? You may also want to move `$match` stages as early as possible, potentially before the `$addFields` to reduce the workload.

Comment: I have to do the $addFields before the $match because I'm matching on those fields. 
Updating the post with index information...

Comment: you can partially move those fields that do not come from `$addFields` first. Also, you may want to consider refactoring your schema if your query is a frequent one, like materializing `lastreportdate` and `name`, avoid storing keydata in object so you don't need to perform `$objectToArray` everytime...

Comment: You should also index`users` on the field `companyref` as it is used in the `$lookup`